# PhpMailer erro ao enviar

Tags: phpmailer

Opa, estou usando uma função propria para envio de email com o phpmailer, segue função

```
function SendMail($acessa_arquivo, $email_destinatario, $nome_destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, $link)
{

    require_once("_files_itens/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");




    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 

    $mail->IsMAIL();

    $mail->Host = 'mail.site.com.br'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = 'nao-responda@site.com.br';
    $mail->Password = '**********';      
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->setFrom('nao-responda@site.com.br', 'site');
    $mail->addAddress($email_destinatario, $nome_destinatario);
    $mail->isHTML(true);  
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body    = $mensagem;
    $mail->AltBody = $mensagem;


        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'OOOO.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Mensagem Enviada';
        }

}
```

A questão é que está funcão funciona perfeitamente, mas, ao tentar reusa-la numa outra página, estou recebendo um erro do phpmailer, que não consegui identificar.

Erro: `Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.`

O email de destinatário está correto, o assunto não ultrapassa 20 caracteres em letras.

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Nao amigao, foquei em outro projeto, deixei este com email um pouco de lado.

Comment: no setFrom tente adicionar um terceiro parâmetro como 0. Ex: $mail->setFrom($email, $nome, 0);

Comment: Outra possível solução na função $mail->addAddress(); deixar apenas um único parâmetro: o email

Comment: Logo após instanciar a variável $mail como  PHPMailer, atribua o seguinte parâmetro: $mail->IsSMTP(); no lugar de $mail->IsMAIL()