# Enviar email usando PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Desde já agradeço a atenção!
Bom eu não tenho muita familiaridade com programação apenas com design. Tentei usar a classe PHPMailer para criar um simples formulário de contato no meu site, procurei aqui algumas dicas mas não tive muito sucesso, pois tudo que vi ja estava um pouco adiantado e não consegui aprender o básico...

Cheguei a instalar o composer e instalar o phpmailer por ele mas travei ali e não consegui seguir sozinho, peço a ajuda aqui caso alguém me aponte o que estou fazendo de errado e como corrigir iria agradecer muito.

CONTACT.HTML

```
       <form id="form" action="vendor/sendmail.php" method="post">
        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Name</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Email</label>
          <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label class="label">Message</label>
          <div class="control">
            <textarea class="textarea" name="mensagem" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field is-grouped">
          <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-link">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

SENDMAIL.PHP (peguei exatamente como estava na documentação e so preenchi meus dados)
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace

```
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];

    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    //Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.eftmkg.com';                      // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'info@eftmkg.com';                  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';                     // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('info@eftmkg.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('kaio.maia.so@gmail.com', 'Kaio Maia');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('info@eftmkg.com');                       // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@eftmkg.com', 'Info');
        //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        //Attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'EFTMKG';
        $mail->Body    = '$mensagem';
        //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Quando eu vou tentar enviar recebo a mensagem de erro:

Could not access file: /var/tmp/file.tar.gz

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Could not access file: /var/tmp/file.tar.gz

Comment: A parte dos attachments são do email, caso esse ficheiro não exista ele não vai dar correto impedindo o email.

Comment: Já deu uma pesquisada aqui no site mesmo? Tem várias respostas similares, pode ser que uma te ajude: essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153820/phpmailer-erro-ao-enviar  
e essa por exemplo:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/229703/envio-de-anexo-com-phpmailer

Comment: Ricardo eu pesquisei sim, mas como eu não tenho noção de programação, qualquer termo no código que seja diferente do meu ja encontro certa dificuldade para compreender...

Answer (score 3):

Se não precisas anexar ficheiros ao email, remove estas linhas. Se quiseres manter o código para mais tarde usares como exemplo, comenta então, usa `//` no inicio da linha para passarem a ser um comentário.

```
//Attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
```

Caso precises de anexar algo ao email, corrige os caminhos, o erro que tens é causado por estes ficheiros não existirem.

Answer (score 3):

#### Motivo:

O erro traduzido: "Não foi possível acessar o arquivo" `file.tar.gz` em `/var/tmp/`, **ou seja, não encontrou o arquivo e/ou a pasta**.

---

#### Resolução:

Como provavelmente você pegou de um exemplo, estas linhas mostram como "anexar" arquivos (mais comum, usado para uma "assinatura digital"), então, como não tem estes arquivos a serem anexados, **comente ou exclua as linhas exemplos de anexos**:

```
//Attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
```

---

[Documentação oficial PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Realmente, eu não percebi isso foi pura falta de atenção minha, olhei pra essas linhas diversas vezes não me liguei que poderiam ser uma feature que não iria utilizar no meu formulário.